# Is there a way to -not- refresh the page when we click on a link in SharePoint Web part?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

A few days ago I submitted this question:
[Sharepoint's "New Folder" doesn't ask for a required field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161708/sharepoints-new-folder-doesnt-ask-for-a-required-field)

I essentially have Web Part Connections filter some documents through a required field. I was having problems making that new field for the folders. I managed to do it with help from  [Moron.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252697/moron)

It is all good and dandy, but now my problem is that whenever someone goes into the folder, the filter gets reset, and you're not able to re-select the same option you were just at. We were very confused for a few minutes when we were playing with it. Does anyone know a solution for this? perhaps a different kind of filter that would allow this? It is pretty important that the filter doesn't refresh when we go into the folder.

Thanks!
-V

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: maybe you should put your filter parameters into the URL? there is a filter web part that maps to query string parameters. From what I saw, this parameters do not get overriden when entering folders